# Grails mocking is failing

Tags: grails, integration-testing, spock

I have written a service for which integration testing is being carried out. The service internally calls an external rest service and populates the value.

### Service class

```
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

class Service {
    final static RestTemplate TEMPLATE = new RestTemplate()

    def getList() {
        final String info = TEMPLATE.getForObject(getHostUrl(), String.class,[:])
        return info
    }
```

To avoid the actual external service  call, I am trying to mock it as below.

```
class ServiceIntegrationSpec extends IntegrationSpec {

    void testList() {
        setup:
            List<Employee> list = new ArrayList<>()
            list.add(new Employee(id:"123", name: "test1"))
            list.add(new Employee(id:"146", name: "test2"))
            def clazz = String.class
            def url  = ""
            def emptyMap = [:]
            rackService.TEMPLATE.metaClass.getForObject = {String url, Class clazz,
            Map emptyMap ->list}

        when:
            def val = service.getList()

        then:
            val != null
    }
}
```

When the integration test is run with the command: grails test-app integration:, I get the following errors:

1. The current scope already contains a variable url
2. The current scope already contains a variable clazz
3. The current scope already contains a variable emptyMap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to define url, clazz and emptyMap beforehand. 
The code

```
        def clazz = String.class
        def url  = ""
        def emptyMap = [:]
        rackService.TEMPLATE.metaClass.getForObject = {String url, Class clazz,
        Map emptyMap ->list}
```

can be  replaced as

```
        rackService.TEMPLATE.metaClass.getForObject = {String url, Class clazz,
        LinkedHashMap emptyMap ->list}
```

Please note that groovy considers this empty map [:]  as LinkedHashMap by default. Please find the reference below:
http://www.javaworld.com/article/2073116/java-collections-default-implementation-choices--groovy-s-opinion.html

Answer (score 0):

You try to rename the variable of metaclass method

```
rackService.TEMPLATE.metaClass.getForObject = {String urlParameter, Class clazzParameter,
        Map emptyMap ->listParameter}
```